# Why does jQuery's one fire immediately when it's added to an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/ypKkr/) a fiddle illustrating the problem.  I am adding a jQuery one binding on the click of one element to the 'html' element.  I am not expecting the 'one' event handler to fire until the next click, but it fires on the click that adds the binding.  This seems to not be a problem if it is a more specific element that the 'one' event handler is added to, but it happens when I use 'html' or 'body' as the element, which is what I want to do.

This doesn't make sense to me, I'd think the first click would add the one for the next click and it wouldn't fire on the click on the link.

By the way, my actual problem could probably be solved in a better way, but I came across this and was curious why it didn't work as I expected.

---

Code:

html:

```
<div id='hello'>hello</div>
<a class="title" href="#">this example</a> is a test​
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.title').click(function() {
        var htmlClickBind = function (e) {
            console.log('clicked on html, e.target = ' + e.target);
            console.log(e.target == '');
            if (!$(e.target).is('a') ) {
                console.log('cleared click event');
            }
            else {
                $('html').one('click', htmlClickBind);
            }
        };

        $('html').one('click', htmlClickBind);
    });
});​
```

Comment: Always include the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you can just as easily copy/paste....

Comment: @Neal it's to prevent link rot B)

Comment: @Neal: And take a full-time job at SO? No, I'd rather teach and suggest people take responsibility for themselves.

Comment: @Snuffleupagus still can copy/paste. it took less time to do that then to create this comment :-)

Comment: @Neal teach a man to fish etc. etc.

Comment: @Neal: You underestimate my typing speed dramatically (and also underestimate how slow jsFiddle is). ;-) I **will** do it for new users. I expect a user with more than 3k rep to be able to do it themselves. Mind, this is all a minor point.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, been a while since I asked a question. I will do this in the future.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder hmmm yea, that is true. I did not notice the OPs rep. I just assumed he did not know better...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `click` event on the `a.target` element bubbles up to the `html` element, where your (just-added) handler sees it.

To prevent this, use `event.stopPropgation` in your `a.target` `click` handler (or `return false`, which does `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault`).

Updated code (see the comments): [Live copy](http://jsfiddle.net/ypKkr/2/)

```
$(function() {
    // Accept the event arg ----v
    $('a.title').click(function(e) {
        // Stop propagation
        e.stopPropagation();
        var htmlClickBind = function (e) {
            console.log('clicked on html, e.target = ' + e.target);
            console.log(e.target == '');
            if (!$(e.target).is('a') ) {
                console.log('cleared click event');
            }
            else {
                $('html').one('click', htmlClickBind);
            }
        };

        $('html').one('click', htmlClickBind);
    });
});​
```

Comment: OK, that makes sense to me now, since the event bubbles up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @rosscj2533: A pleasure! Glad that helped. Best,